# OnClick event for dynamic TImage

Tags: onclick, c++builder, c++builder-6, timage

I am trying to build a memory game with 16 pairs of cards.

I do not know exactly how to implement an `OnClick` event. I am new at using C++Builder, so please help.

The images are in an array, I allocate them dynamically like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 8 ; j++)
    {
        VectorOfImages[i*8+j]=new Card(9+i*112,9+j*112,pan, 0);
        VectorOfImages[i*8+j]->image->Picture>LoadFromFile("...OOP\\c\\images\\0.bmp");
        VectorOfImages[i*8+j]->image->Tag=i*8+j;
        VectorOfImages[i*8+j]->image->Enabled=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`OnClick` is a property of `TImage`, you can assign it like you would any other property, eg:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
        int idx = (i*8) + j;
        VectorOfImages[idx] = new Card(9+i*112, 9+j*112, pan, 0);
        VectorOfImages[idx]->image->Picture->LoadFromFile("...OOP\\c\\images\\0.bmp");
        VectorOfImages[idx]->image->Tag = idx;
        VectorOfImages[idx]->image->Enabled = false;
        VectorOfImages[idx]->OnClick = &ImageClicked; // <-- here
    }
}
```

Then, add `ImageClicked()` to your Form:

```cpp
private:
    void __fastcall ImageClicked(TObject *Sender);

...

void __fastcall TMyForm::ImageClicked(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Sender points at the TImage that was clicked...
    TImage *Image = static_cast<TImage*>(Sender);
    // use Image as needed...
}
```

Comment: Oh, my Goddd!! Thank you so much, I will try